# images in Aptana 3 project not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, aptana3

I am adding images to an existing webapp, using Aptana 3 on Windows 7.

First I cut and pasted the images into a folder, but that didn't work, so then I created a new folder in my project directory and imported the files.  When I run the code I get an error in Firebug saying 'file not found'.

I can click on the image from the Aptana directory, and it opens in Windows Photo Viewer.  The path given is the same as the path given by Firebug.  I have refreshed the folder and its enclosing folders, and have ran the app with IE, Firefox and Chrome, but still I cannot see the images in my app.

I tried running the code using Aptana's internal server (set to Firefox) and also tried to mount the code on our development server...no images in either case.

The images are added in the HTML/CSS like so:

(HTML:)

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

(CSS:)

```
.image{
height:15px;
width:15px;
background-image: url(../images/legend/image.png);
background-position: center top;
```

}

..In the existing code, there are several other images added in exactly the same way (by someone else), and these images show up in the app.

Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Is the CSS inside of `<style></style>` tags and you have just left them out when you pasted your code in?

Comment: I edited my question...the line at the top is HTML, below that is CSS...from an HTML file and CSS file respectively

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `../` from the "background-image" so it looks like this

```
background-image: url(images/legend/image.png);
```

Answer (score 0):

well, I tried to create a new folder and re-import the files, and now it worked..the only thing I did differently is change 'legend' to 'mapLegend' as I noticed that 'legend' was highlighted in Aptana; I found that 'legend' is a keyword in HTML....so maybe that was it, or maybe it was some hiccup in Aptana, I'm not sure....
The answer posted above wouldn't work for me, b/c I needed to ascend one level in the directory to be on the correct relative path...